# Difference between `No such file or directory` and ``No such device or address

Tags: 12.04, vpn, pptp

Recently, I tried to install a PPTP VPN on my OpenVZ VPS Ubuntu 12.04.

I followed the online tutorial and tried:

```
cat /dev/ppp
```

Output is:

```
cat: /dev/ppp: No such file or directory
```

It turns out in this situation your VPS can NOT install PPTP VPN.

The correct output should be:

```
cat: /dev/ppp: No such device or address
```

What is the difference? The two outputs look similar but turn out to be totally different.